# What is the relation between PipeWire and PulseAudio on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, 22.04, desktop-environments, pipewire

**Background of the question:** I'm playing with Pop!_OS in a virtual machine and trying to setup the audio for the xRDP service. At this moment it looks like it is not possible because they've [switched](https://support.system76.com/articles/audio/) to PipeWire and for some reason its PulseAudio wrapper is not fully compatible with the package `xrdp-pulseaudio-installer`... nor with the building process mentioned below.

In addition on Ubuntu 18.04 I was using the package `xrdp-pulseaudio-installer` which for some reason is not available on Ubuntu 19.04+ (nor the package `pulseaudio-module-xrdp` which is available on Kali). So we need to build it manually as it is described in [this topic](https://gist.github.com/rkttu/35ecab5604c9ddc356b0af4644d5a226).

---

**The question:**
Initially I was thinking PipeWire is a newer audio service and it has a PulseAudio wrapper for backward compatibility. But I found on my Ubuntu 22.04 both services are enabled and running. Or at least both commands below report `active (running)`.

```bash
systemctl --user status pulseaudio.service
systemctl --user status pipewire.service
```

So my questions are:

- What is the relation between PipeWire and PulseAudio on Ubuntu 22.04?
- How to determinate which of them actually provides the audio on my system?

Comment: PipeWire isn't default until Ubuntu 22.10 (currently Ubuntu *kinetic*).  Pulseaudio is default for 22.04 (*jammy*), though Pop OS use packages/kernel from *testing* which is often *kinetic* or the next release of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the relation between PipeWire and PulseAudio on Ubuntu 22.04?

From what I understand, while the PipeWire service is installed by default in Ubuntu 22.04, it does not fully replace the PulseAudio service (yet). However, if you'd like to try, you can follow the instructions in [How to Use PipeWire to replace PulseAudio in Ubuntu 22.04](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/04/pipewire-replace-pulseaudio-ubuntu-2204/).

> How to determinate which of them actually provides the audio on my system?

```
pactl info | grep 'Server Name'
```

This will show "pulseaudio" for PulseAudio, and "PulseAudio (on PipeWire ...)" for PipeWire.